# code error deleting rows of empty cells in openpyxl 'TypeError: 'Cell' object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm writing the code for the below task for an excel automation task.

If the cell contents in column 'C' are empty, the entire row of that cell is deleted.

[image]

example image

If you look at the image above, rows 5, 7, 9, and 11 of column 'C' are empty, so I need to delete those rows.

Here is the code I wrote for the above task.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
ws=wb.worksheets[0]


for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        if cell[2].value == None:
            ws.delete_rows(row, 1)
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
C:\project\b>C:/python39-32/python.exe c:/project/b/ex.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\project\b\ex.py", line 46, in <module>
    if cell[2].value == None:
TypeError: 'Cell' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You probably mean `if row[2].value is None`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is `row` is not an integer (not row number) but the whole row. To achieve what you are looking for, you need to iterate using row numbers. Below code is a way to achieve this.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
ws=wb.worksheets[0]

i=1  # I am checking all rows, including header. Change to '2' if you want to skip header row
while i <= ws.max_row:
    if ws.cell(row=i, column=3).value == None: #Check 3rd column of each row for None
        ws.delete_rows(i, 1)
        # No i+1 here as the row below will move up by one and you need to check that as well
    else:
        i += 1

wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

**Options - 2**
Based on @Charlieclark's suggestion, here is another way to delete the rows. Iterate in reverse order and delete the rows where 3rd column is blank. Certainly more elegant and shorter

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
ws=wb.worksheets[0]

for row in reversed(list(ws.rows)):
    if row[2].value is None:
        ws.delete_rows(row[0].row, 1)

wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: The above code works fine. I'll have to study more. thank you.

Comment: The fix is even easier, see my comment above. You also need to consider altering a mutable while looping over it.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark. I did try that, but it failed in the next step ````ws.delete_rows(row, 1)```` with msg - ````TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'````. Also, in the above case, @goni is looking for deleting row if column 3 is blank, not any cell

Comment: You do need to delete the row index: `cell.row` but doing this will affect the length of the worksheet so you need to delete from the bottom up.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark !! Did the reverse traversal and deleted the appropriate rows. Didn't need ````cell.row```` as I used ````enumerate```` for the index. Certainly more elegant....

Comment: Using enumerate on top any of the built-in methods is overkill. You also don't need to call ws.cell as the cell is in the row.

Comment: Alright, done... removed enumerate and calling ws.cell as well. Think it now cut down to max